# Strange python dict behavior

Tags: python, dictionary

Can someone explain this behavior for me?

```
mapping = dict.fromkeys([1, 2, 3], [])
objects = [{'pk': 1}, {'pk': 2}, {'pk': 3}]

for obj in objects:
    pk = obj['pk']
    mapping[pk].append(obj)

print mapping

# expected: {1: [{'pk': 1}], 2: [{'pk': 2}], 3: [{'pk': 3}]}
# got: {1: [{'pk': 1}, {'pk': 2}, {'pk': 3}], 2: [{'pk': 1}, {'pk': 2}, {'pk': 3}], 3: [{'pk': 1}, {'pk': 2}, {'pk': 3}]}
```

I'm attempting to map the dicts in `objects` to another dict whose keys are properties of the original dict. Assume the `objects` list contains several objects of each unique PK (the reason I'm not just using `map` here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because in:

```
  mapping = dict.fromkeys([1, 2, 3], [])
```

`[]` is evaluated once, so each key has the same list as value. Try using `collections.defaultdict` instead.

Comment: :facepalm: Thank you. (I'll accept the answer in exactly 8 minutes for some reason)

Answer (score 1):

If you change `mapping` as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict
mapping = defaultdict(list)
```

and keep the rest as-is, the code will do what you expect.

The problem with your current code is that all three keys of `mapping` map to the same list. When you append an element to one, you are effectively appending it to all.

Answer (score 1):

It happens, because within this line:

```
mapping = dict.fromkeys([1, 2, 3], [])
```

you assign the same list to each key. And because lists are mutable, by modifying list for one key, you modify the list for other keys at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

On line 1, the use of the expression [] causes an empty list to be created.

This is the only empty list object that appears in the above snippet. When dict.fromkeys runs, it does NOT make three different copies of the empty list. Instead, it makes three references to the SAME empty list.

Thus during the loop later on, each time you add another number into the empty list, it's the same list.